# Set the hidden radio button value through autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When a user messages another user. They can pick which type of profile to send to. (Common or Manager)... I'm checking in the backend which profile to send it to with "recipient_type", How do I get my autocomplete to choose the hidden radio button for me?

The autocomplete looks like this:
*To*: `John Doe - Manager`
or
*To:* `John Doe`

template:

```
<div class="hide">
     <input type="radio" id="id_recipient_type" name="recipient_type" value="0" />
     <input type="radio" id="id_recipient_type" name="recipient_type" value="1" />
</div>
<div class="inline-block">
     <label for="id_omnibox"></label>
     <input type="hidden" name="recipient_username" id="id_recipient_username" />
     <input id="message-to" class="required input-text" style="width: 145%;"name="omnibox" placeholder="Search for user..." autocomplte="on" type="text" />
</div>
```

script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.get('/autocomplete/message/', function(data) {
        var completions = new Array();
        var dict = JSON.parse(data, function(key, value) {
            completions.push(key);
            return value;
        });
        $('#message-to').autocomplete({
            source: completions,
            minLength: 1,
            select: function(value, data){
                $('#id_recipient_username').val(dict[data.item.value])
                split_string = data.item.value.split("- ");
                $('#id_recipient_type_'+(split_string[1]=="Manager"?"1":"0")).attr('checked', true);
            }     
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that in order to your code to work you need to change or:

```
<div class="hide">
     <input type="radio" id="id_recipient_type_0" name="recipient_type" value="0" />
     <input type="radio" id="id_recipient_type_1" name="recipient_type" value="1" />
</div>
```

Radio boxes IDs. or:

```
$('#id_recipient_type[value="'+(split_string[1]=="Manager"?"1":"0")+'"]').attr('checked', true);
```

The jquery selector to `#id_recipient_type[value="1"]` or `#id_recipient_type[value="0"]`.

I'd ratter use the first solution, since in html ids should be unique.

You need to solve a problem stated by [kmfk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/396318/kmfk) with your split where it throws an error when don't find the `' - '` string, so change:

```
split_string = data.item.value.split("- ");
```

To:

```
split_string = 'John Doe - Manage'.match(/ - (Manager)$/)
split_string = split_string != null ? "0" : "1";
```

Comment: +1. had to edit my answer, noticed the IDs didn't exist but didnt mention it.  would still run into an issue with an undefined error on the `split_string[1]` when "- " doesn't exist in the string.

Comment: Agreed, I'll change my answer to work with regex. Thanks for the note.

Answer (score 1):

Looking through your code example, these lines appear to be the issue:

```
split_string = data.item.value.split("- ");
$('#id_recipient_type_'+(split_string[1]=="Manager"?"1":"0")).attr('checked', true);
```

That split will be an issue when `- Manager` is not in the the string - and the IDs you are looking for don't exist.

Maybe do:

```
var valAttr = data.item.value.indexOf("- Manager") > 0 ? 1 : 0;
$('#id_recipient_type [value="'+valAttr+'"]').attr('checked', true);
```